# css class iframe or standalone

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want a different a CSS attribute (the overflow) depending if the page is displaying inside a (Facebook) iframe, or on its own.

I know that I can add a bit of Javascript (`if (top === window) {...}`), but I think a pure CSS solution will be tidier.

So is there any way to make a CSS selector to match only if the page is within an IFrame?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It is bit hazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

CSS operates on the current document only.